# Placing a section between title of part and title of the following chapter

Tags: header-footer

The problem is that I have to enter text in-between the Part title and the start of the next chapter. The text serves as an introduction to the chapters that follow in this Part. The test might span multiple pages and may have sections of its own which may or may not be numbered.

But when I am trying to write a section the page header shows the last section in the previous part.

I want a way to get rid of the section number in the header for only these sections to see the section title of the current section.

The MWE is as below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\begin{document}

\begin{part}{part 1}
\chapter{chap 1}
\section{section 1}
\end{part}

\begin{part}{part 2}
% Problem : The header of this page shows 1.1 SECTION 1%
\section*{Introduction}   
\chapter{chap 2}
\section{section 1}
\end{part}

\end{document}
```

[image: Note that Section numbering]

Comment: `\markboth{}{}`

Comment: Off-topic: Why not `\chapter*{}`?

Comment: @cfr `\chapter*{}` only deals with the first page but subsequent pages have the last chapter in the header or the last section in the header based on odd or even page.

Comment: @Johannes_B `\markboth{}{}` is a neat trick for handling the problem and as of now I can use this as a workaround. Thanks :D

Comment: I said it was off-topic.

Comment: One should mentioni, that the syntax used in the example is wrong.